# Rails: Every user has a own database user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My customer has a existing database where every user has it's own database user and he wants that every user uses his own database user to log into the rails application.

For my models of this database I use `ActiveRecord::Base::establish_connection` to connect with the username and password of the login form.

Now I thought to close this connection in an `after_filter` so no other user can get this connection from the connection pool. But this doen't work.

I want something like this in my controller:

```
class Demo < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_filter :connect
    after_filter  :close_connection

    def action
       # do some stuff with the database
    end
end
```

How can I achive this with `ActiveRecord` or is there a better solution for this problem? Or is there an other ORM mapper that my be better for this problem?

**I can't change the database or the fact that every user has its own database user that he needs to login becuase my customer does use this structure for other applications :(**

*It's a Postgres database. And Rails 3.2.13 (JRuby).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I've never developed this kind of authentication system, but if I had to I would do probably choose [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden), which is an authentication system integrated as a [rack middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware).

Warden allows to build your own [authentication strategies](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies). So I made an example for your case, but be aware that it does not work. It is just for the sake of clarity.

The idea is to reconfigure your database pool with a given username/password in a rack middleware. Rack middlewares are the first components called in a request, so I think it should avoid performance issues.

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:database_user) do

  def valid?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
  end

  def authenticate!
    # Disconnects all connections in the pool, and clears the pool.
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

    # Reconfigure the pool with the new username/password
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['username'] = params[:username]
    config['password'] = params[:password]

    # Establish connection with the new configuration
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

    # Check if the connection works
    # It means that the username/password is correct
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
      user = build_user(params[:username])
      success!(user)
    else
      fail!("Wrong username/password")
    end

  rescue # Errors thrown by Postgres
    fail!("Wrong username/password")
  end

  private

    def build_user(username)
      OpenStruct.new({username: username}) # Dynamic object
    end
end
```

Then configure Warden in your Rails configuration file.

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use RailsWarden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :database_user
  manager.failure_app = LoginController
end
```

Once again this is just a prototype to give you an insight of how you could resolve your problem. I hope that will help you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try this when I'm back at the office.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good choice to reset connection on each request per user. Most importantly it looses the db cache as you have to initiate connection in each request.

Better try to use Mongodb (if possible) where each record will belong to  a user and everything of that user will be under that record. This solutions is possible if you are trying to develop a system. Existing system with giant db might consider this solution impossible :)

Comment: Using mongo it is possible to do sharding

Comment: This was in my mind too, but there is no way using mongodb :(